# to submit iPhone application to app store do we need our own server in all cases?

Tags: iphone, sdk, payment, storekit

i read [this overview of the StoreKit API](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Overview%20of%20the%20Store%20Kit%20API/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html)
but could not understand the role of developer's server exactly,
will you please elaborate the role and is it mandatory to have if i need to submit an application ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only if you are following the Server Product Model or if you need to do subscriptions are you required to have a server. If you follow the Built-in Product Model, then you can use Apple's servers to do the payment, and then you will enable functionality based on if the user had previously purchased the item.

See [In App Purchase Programming Guide: #Feature Delivery](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Overview%20of%20the%20Store%20Kit%20API/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW12)

Also, this is only if you are using StoreKit for in app purchases. It is not required to use this framework for simple iPhone applications.